# Transit in Curaçao

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, transit, indian-citizens

I am a Indian passport holder and have booked a single ticket from New Delhi to Port of Spain via Amsterdam and Curaçao. From New Delhi to Curaçao, I am traveling by KLM and from Curaçao to Port of Spain, by Insel air. Although I booked single ticket, The KLM authorities told me that I will receive my luggage in Curaçao and I will have to get boarding pass for Curaçao to Port of Spain in Curaçao. I don't have any visa for Curaçao. Do I need to pass through immigration for getting my luggage for recheck in or it will be automatically transferred to Insel Air at Curaçao?

Comment: @Phil the traveler in the other question required a uniform short-stay Schengen visa to retrieve and re-check luggage in Amsterdam, and that visa exempted the traveler from needing a visa for Curaçao.  This traveler does not need a uniform short-stay Schengen visa in Amsterdam, so the answer to the other question is not applicable in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You **always** need to clear immigration to pick up luggage.

So yes, you will need a visa for Curacao, which you apply for at the Dutch embassy.